# HTML h1 is being aligned to bottom of img

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an img and then a h1 beside it in a header. Here is the code:

```
<header class="site-header">
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="site-logo">
  <div class="first-level-header">
    <h1>Name of website</h1>
  </div>
</header><!-- /site-header -->
```

And the css:

```
h1 {
display: inline;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: blue;
}

img.site-logo {
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

My question is: how do I have the h1 stay on the top instead of being aligned to the bottom of the image.

More information: This is a wordpress theme, if that means anything. I have also tried other tons of things, different images, different places in the document, changing the h1 to a p, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Top means, where exactly you want. Before image or next to image?

Comment: Next to the image, but not aligned to the bottom; aligned to the top.

Comment: have u tried my below code.. it will align next to the image and align to top only..

Comment: I have given a css for the class img.site-logo, please use this and check it will work

Answer (score 1):

After testing for hours I found that if you surround the h1 with a div and set the div to vertical-align: top; it works.

Example:

HTML:

```
<header class="site-header">
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="site-logo">
  <div class="first-level-header">
    <h1>Name of website</h1>
  </div>
</header><!-- /site-header -->
```

CSS:

```
.first-level-header {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

 h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}

img.site-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a vertical-align element. For example, in your CSS you can add:

```
vertical-align: center
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want next to that image follow this css:

```
img.site-logo {
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  float:left;
}
```

If you want above the image follw this html:

```
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="first-level-header">
    <h1>Name of website</h1>
  </div>
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="site-logo">

</header><!-- /site-header -->
```